How to ensure pagehide handler has enough time to execute before page is navigated away
I am using the below to try to perform some action before the page is navigated away, but unfortunately there is not enough time for the action to fully execute before that happens:
window.addEventListener('pagehide', (event) => {
    ...
});

For more context, the above is part of a page I have embedded as an iframe inside of Qualtrics (a survey platform), and the pagehide is used to detect when the user clicks next in the survey. I've tried using the beforeunload event, but that is not triggered by when the user clicks next.
The action I want to perform is writing to a Firebase database, but it seems connection is lost to it before it can fully do so.
My question is: Is there any way to ensure that the event handler for pagehide has enough time to execute before the page is navigated away? Or a way to maintain the Firebase connection long enough for data to be written to. Alternatively, are there other methods for detecting when the user clicks next on the survey page before the page basically gets destroyed?

Have you tried using a promise with .then?
